# How to handle permission in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-6, cancancan

Normal User adds a post to the system, he then has the ability to update and delete this post. In the future, he may want to assign other users the ability to edit, delete, update etc.

My models are

```
class Post
  has_many :post_users
  has_many :users, through: :post_users
end

class PostUser
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end

class User
  has_many :post_users
  has_many :posts, through: :post_users
end
```

I need something like this in my ability.rb

```
user ||= User.new # guest user (not logged in)

can :read, :all
can :manage, Post, postuser: postuser.user.id
```

So I could manage posts only when in clients_users table is a record with user_id and id of this post. How do I make it work?

Comment: You might want to look into gems like [pundit](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) or [cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan).

Comment: How do I use cancancan do manage the form?

Answer (score 0):

I have not used cancancan gem.
But reading through your `add_user` action and cancancan documentation for [Defining abilities for associations](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan/wiki/Defining-Abilities#hash-of-conditions), I think you need to define you code similar to following:

```
class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    if user.present?  # additional permissions for logged in users (they can read their own posts)
      can :manage, Post, post_users: { user_id: user.id }
    end
  end
end
```

Try and let me know if you face any issues. Might need some debugging and changes.

Comment: My main issue is around the cancancan, how do I set it so that it grants the permission it needs to grant

Comment: @MozartLen Yes. That's what I mentioned in my answer. You will need to setup Anility similar to mentioned above. So when a current_user tries accessing it checks if the user is present in set of users of that particular post.
Is this not what you are looking for?

Comment: @MozartLen I have updated answer as per your edits in question